# Prevent leaflet from zooming after adding a route

Tags: leaflet, routing

The [leaflet routing machine hello world](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/) adds a route on the map and automatically zooms to fit the route.

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
    L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
  ]
}).addTo(map);
```

How can I prevent this zooming from happening? I just want to add the route, and that nothing moves or zooms anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option I searched was `fitSelectedRoutes`, setting it to `false` does the job.

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
    L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
  ],
  fitSelectedRoutes: false,
}).addTo(map);
```